# Given the language $L=\{w\in\{a,b\}^*\mid\text{$w$ has an odd quantity of $a$ and even quantity of $b$}\}$ answer

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

> Find a finite automaton that recognizes the language $$L=\{w\in\{a,b\}^*\mid\text{$w$ has an odd quantity of $a$ and an even quantity of $b$}\}.$$ Indicate whether the automata is deterministic or not.

---

I tried to find a regular expression for $L$: $$(a(aa)^*+(bb)^*)^*$$ but then I realized that $\lambda\notin L$ since there is not odd quantity of $a$, so my final regex is $$(a(aa)^*+(bb)^*)^+$$ I am not able to find an automata for this language. I tried with:

[image: My attempt]

but if we call $z=a(aa)^*+(bb)^*$ then **I am not able to graph $z^+$.**

How can we get the automata?

Comment: Oh, this is not correct. We could have $ababa\in L$ but my regex does not include it.

Comment: And on the other hand, your regular expression incorrectly accepts $abba$.

Comment: My approach to constructing a finite state machine would be to let the states be members of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \times (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ corresponding to (number of $a$ mod 2, number of $b$ mod 2).

Comment: I do not understand your approach. Why $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}=\{\overline0,\overline1\}$ to both letters if one of them has to be odd/even? Could you detail your comment please?

Comment: OK, for another hint: the initial state would be $(\bar 0, \bar 0)$ and the only accepting state would be $(\bar 1, \bar 0)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler so are you proposing a finite state machine of ordered pairs?